# In the sentence, "best three games out of five", is "best" used as a verb?

Tags: word-usage

Some guy [explains MLB Division Series](https://youtu.be/_fJos-GPZcc?t=156) this way

> the division series is **best** three games out of five, so if you win three
>   games you advance to the next round

where "best" seems to be a verb.

As per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/best), it is grammatically correct to use best as a verb.

> to defeat someone in a fight or competition
>
> He **bested** his opponent in just two rounds.

Is it the same use as the quotation at the beginning?

Comment: "Best" is actually used as an adjective in the sentence "The division series is best three games out of five." You could put "the" before "best" ("the best three games out of five") but it isn't necessary with a plural noun (games). That is, "I play games" and "I play the games" are both grammatical depending on your meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiomatic phrase, so don't worry too much about the grammar of it. "Best" is here being used as an *adjective* and means *the most of*, or *the majority of* something. An example of the word being used to mean the most, or the majority is "*he ate the best part of that cake*".

When you play "best three out of five" it means that the person who wins three games out of the five will be considered the overall winner, because they won *most of* the games.

It wouldn't make any sense to say that the adjective described an individual game in the tournament because both players could win *some* of the 5 games.